# iTunes Smart Playlist... comparing values across playlists?

Tags: itunes, applescript, smart-playlist

I'm not entirely sure this is possible at present, though I am tantalizingly close! Maybe with "nested" criteria for the smart playlist...?

I'm a keen editor / remixer of tracks. Every time I edit a track, I add the term "edit" to the end of the track name.

So my iTunes looks like this:

```
Track 1
Track 1 edited
Track 2
Track 2 edited
Track 3
Track 4
Track 5
Track 5 edited
```

So it's easy to get the tracks that have been edited:

NAME contains "edited"

Likewise the unedited versions of all tracks:

NAME does not contain "edited"

But I want to try and find the tracks that have not been edited yet (that's track 3 and 4 in the above example)

Is this kind of logic possible in Smart Playlists? I'm stumped. I feel like there is some clever way to use nested logic (which I only just found out about!)

Let me know your thoughts.